# Magento 1.7x version- Last day of support?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, magento-1

What is the last day we can use Magento 1.7 while still receive support from Magento developers?
I heard its 2-3 years after Magento 2.0 release but no specific date has been published.
Any ideas when it would be the smart time to upgrade from 1.7 to 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know the official support of Magento 1.x will last for 3 years after Magento 2.0 came out of beta. So it'll probably be around November 2018

More information can be found on the forums: https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/What-is-the-end-of-life-date-for-Magento-1-9x-community-edition/td-p/36541

Comment: I am not sure if they ever included 1.7 in this statement though. Might just be for 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

As a Certified Magento Developer, I can tell you that you will have no shortage of devs available to work on your Magento 1 site for a long time. Magento 2 is still undergoing changes and there are still bugs within the software. I would recommend waiting a good while before making the move to upgrade.

Comment: I am more concerned about security, if support for 1.x will stop after 3 years... then essentially no one will look after security aspects.

Comment: Since you are not on Enterprise edition,  I can't imagine that you are getting support directly from Magento, but rather freelance developers. Freelancers will be working on M1 for a long time.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that SUPEE security patches are released by freelancers. I though they are released by developers working in Magento. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Yes I think I misunderstood what you meant when you said support, it occurred to me later that you were referring to patches. Sorry about that!